# for loop iterate two time in jquery automatically

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, iteration, auto

I am trying to get data by calling api and put data into table. I found three length of data in object type. Then when I want to show it on table it shows six row but I want three row. When I debugged the code I have noticed that the index of for loop iterate 0-2(that is correct exactly I want) but this for loop is calling second time auto and start the index 0-2(that my issues) that's why may be it shows 3+3 = 6 row in my column. I am not sure what's the exact issues. How can I solve this Issues?

This is my script:
$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $.post('http://localhost/..., function (data) {
            var leaveList = data.data;
            var keys = Object.keys(leaveList);

            var len = keys.length;
            //alert(len);

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               
                if (leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] == 'SL') {
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] + ' </td><td> Sick Leave </td> <td> ' + leaveList[i]["absLimiteDimension"] + ' </td> <td>' + leaveList[i]["calculated"] + '</td> </tr>'
                } else if (leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] == 'CL') {
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] + ' </td><td> Casual Leave </td> <td> ' + leaveList[i]["absLimiteDimension"] + ' </td> <td>' + leaveList[i]["calculated"] + '</td> </tr>'
                } else if (leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] == 'EL') {
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] + ' </td><td> Earned Leave </td> <td> ' + leaveList[i]["absLimiteDimension"] + ' </td> <td>' + leaveList[i]["calculated"] + '</td> </tr>'
                } else if (leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] == 'ML') {
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] + ' </td><td> Maternity Leave </td> <td> ' + leaveList[i]["absLimiteDimension"] + ' </td> <td>' + leaveList[i]["calculated"] + '</td> </tr>'
                } else if (leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] == 'VL') {
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] + ' </td><td> Visit Leave </td> <td> ' + leaveList[i]["absLimiteDimension"] + ' </td> <td>' + leaveList[i]["calculated"] + '</td> </tr>'
                } else {
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + leaveList[i]["absenceTypeID"] + ' </td><td> Earned Leave (Carry) </td> <td> ' + leaveList[i]["absLimiteDimension"] + ' </td> <td>' + leaveList[i]["calculated"] + '</td> </tr>'
                }

               

            }
           
        });
```

});

Comment: For me with jquery I used to use `$.each(leaveList , function( index , obj ){  //console.log(obj);  })` instead of using keys and `for` loop .. it will not answer your question but it may help .. And to get more help you need to provide a sample of the `console.log(leaveList)`

Comment: I have used each loop also but faced the same issues

Comment: Ok I got it.. your code printed the data twice and you don't know from where the second call is coming? right?! mm. you may include the same `<script src="yourfile.js"></script>` twice or you repeat the code in another place.. to check this comment all of the `/* $.post.. */` code then check if the data returned then the code is repeated else where .. if you don't get the data at all so you include the same `<script src="samesrc.js">` twice